# Question on Graph Theory, Proving T \ P is a tree with fewer leaves

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to show that in any tree T, there is a path P, such that either T = P or T \ P is a tree with fewer leaves.

How could I do this? I would like to begin by showing a trivial case if you just remove a path with one node, then the remaining will still be a tree. However, I do not really understand this question entirely because if you remove one path, then won't the remaining tree not be connected anymore?

Comment: If you remove a maximal path, either you will have removed the whole tree, or the root had exactly two children, or you will have disconnected the graph and will have a forest but not a tree. However, a path in a graph need not be maximal.

Comment: there is a path P 

is different from 

for all path P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the trivial path on a leaf.